# Problem installing apps through Zorin OS terminal "please insert the disc"

Tags: software-installation, zorin

I try to install apps like TLP on my system through the terminal. It keeps giving the following message:

```
**Media change: please insert the disc labeled
 'Zorin-OS 15.2 Lite 32bit'
in the drive '/media/cdrom/' and press [Enter] **
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zorin is looking for CD-ROM in `/etc/apt/sources.list`, but it can't find it so it asks you to insert a disc. To fix this run the following command:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Remove any lines that include CD-ROM from the sources.list file, and save the file.

<sub>**Nano text editor keyboard shortcuts**</sub>
<sub>Use the keyboard combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> and after that press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to save the file to its current location.</sub>
<sub>Use the keyboard combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> to exit nano.</sub>

Update the list of available software.

```
sudo apt update
```

Now try to install the apps again.

Comment: Wow you are truly a genious ...it work perfect.

Answer (score 0):

I have overcome this problem by following the instructions [given by karel](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/594286/165104).
I did the following:

1. open the terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>)
2. enter the command `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list`
3. on the first line I did comment out the line with CD ROM using `#` symbol... you can also delete the line; it's optional.
4. save (<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>  then press <kbd>enter</kbd> key)
5. exit (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>)

IT WORKS PERFECTLY.
Thanks to karel.

Comment: You can use your [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/594176/edit) button below your question to extend it. No need for additional comments ;-)